# Find all invariant subspaces - checking

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $f \in L(V,V)$ has $\dim V = n$ and has $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Find all invariant subspaces.

My try:

Let $A= span\{v_1,…,v_n  \}$ be an eigenbasis of $f$ and $\{a_1, …,a_n  \}$ distinct eigenvalues such that $f(v_i)=a_i\cdot v_i$ I claim that invariant subspaces are defined by choosing subsets of $A$.

proof by induction for $n=1$ we have $A=span\{v_1\}$ so for any combination of $v_1$ we have $f(c\cdot v_1)=c \cdot a_1 v_1 \in A$ let's assume it's true for $n-1$ then for n we have $f(c_1v_1+…+c_nv_n)=a+c_na_nv_n$ where $a \in A$ from inductive assumptions and we have $c_na_nv_n \in A$ as well so any subset of $A$ is an invariant subspace

is my reasiong correct ? or I'm missing something ?